# How to scan and map shares in LAN

Tags: lan, vbscript, scanning

My share drives get disconnected all the time, and after applying different fixes I found on the internet, they still do disconnect.
So everytime, I need to scan the LAN and manually reconnect whatever shares are disconnected.
I was wondering if I could automate this process with a script that scans my LAN and maps the disconnected the share drives.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: I find NET USE z:  \\computername\share to be very durable. My shares do not disconnect.

Comment: If you are in a domain, and you get the network shares through group policy, then its likely that your domain admin misconfigured the GPO. GPO is refreshed in the background every so often, and if they use the replace option, it deletes and then recreates the network share. Bad network connectivity can cause these drives to show up as disconnected.

Comment: Also, if they are disconnected but you know they are not, have you tried doubleclicking the drives? Normally in the This PC view, main view, this reconnects the drives. Note, using the tree on the left does not.

Comment: So if they are setup with Group Policy and you are connected to the domain and simply double-clicking does not make them reappear, you can try command prompt `gpupdate /Target:User /Wait:0` to automate/speed up. Otherwise, having a script to map them with the `net use` can be useful.